# What does clang do if more than one optimization flag is set?

Tags: c, clang, clang++

E.g., what happens when you type `clang -O3 -O0`?

Is the behavior the same as in `gcc`? I.e., all but the last optimization flags are ignored (described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5557261/gcc-multiple-optimization-flags) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61830977/what-does-gcc-and-clang-do-if-you-specify-more-than-one-optimization-flag-toge))?

I looked up in the manual page for `clang` but couldn't find an explanation in the optimization flag section.

Is it undefined behaviour?

Comment: While I don't really know, I would be surprised it it didn't work like GCC, i.e. used only the last option. Worst case, if you *really* need to know, you could always look through the source.

Comment: You could easily test this by writing a program that generates warnings for certain optimizations.

Comment: It is a pretty common behavior for commands of all sorts to have later options override earlier options. (This facilitates defining aliases or makefile macros to act as commands with defaults that can be modified by specifying more options when the alias or macro is used.) Clang ought to document it, but I would regard failure to do so as lax documentation rather than “undefined behavior.”

Comment: @klutt: Testing specific cases does not prove universal rules.

Comment: Why do you wonder? I have a hard time to see any good use of this. Are you just curious?

Comment: "undefined behavior" is a well defined term that refers to behvior of the program you get after compiling it. Of course you can use it colloquially to describe what a compiler does, but it is at least misleading

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 "Iunno behaviour".

Comment: ...of course we cannot exclude the possiblity of a compiler itself having undefined behavior, but a compiler that invokes ub for something as common as passing an argument twice can be considered very broken

Comment: @klutt: There are good use cases. I have an `ecc` alias defined in my shell that compiles with my preferred options (nine of them). The fact that later options override earlier options allows me to use the alias with changes to one or a few of those for a specific situation.

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818: The C standard’s definition of “undefined behavior” applies only within the C standard. Outside of the C standard, it is generic English that may be used to describe situations where behavior is not defined by whatever documentation is relevant.

Comment: @EricPostpischil more or less what I wrote. I still find it a little confusing to use the term in this context.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah, that's true

Comment: @klutt the usecase is overriding optimization options for targets (unittests) in a subdirectory with `cmake`.

Comment: ok, from your comments I understand that overriding options is so common that we can assume that this is also `clang`'s behavior.

Comment: Hmmm, for what reason don't you want optimizations for the unit tests?

Comment: @klutt in order to debug them quickly if they fail at some point. I thought decreasing the optimization level would help the `-g` flag work better.

Comment: @Lime91 That is certainly true. However, remember that some bugs only manifest themselves with certain optimizations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though a test case does not provide a definitive proof of uniform behavior throughout, it may hint on one or another direction, from what I was able to observe in test cases for `Clang` in several versions both with C and C++ code, it appears that, as in `GCC`, the previous conflicting flags are ignored and the last one stands. I did look into the `Clang` documentation and it appears no mention is made about this situation.

[Sample C program with Clang 11.0.1](https://godbolt.org/z/oY6hr9)

The assumption may be that this will not be an issue and that *obviously* the last flag is the one that stands. One might argue that is not so obvious, for example, an argument can be made that the *higher* optimization level should stand.

As to why it was not documented, one can only speculate, maybe lack of awareness of the situation lead to it. The fact is that this should at least, as in GCC, be documented.

Comment: I agree with you. To me (a person without a ton of experience) this was not obvious. Also, I wonder why they don't simply introduce a warning for this case.

Comment: @Lime91 That's a fair point, and a good solution, maybe lack of awareness of the situation lead to it not being addressed. It should at least, as in GCC, be documented.

Answer (score 4):

I have no documentation to support it, but this test indicates it picks the last one:

```
klutt@desktop:/tmp$ clang f.c -O3; ls -l a.out
-rwxr-xr-x 1 klutt klutt 16752 Mar 19 15:37 a.out
klutt@desktop:/tmp$ clang f.c -O0; ls -l a.out
-rwxr-xr-x 1 klutt klutt 16704 Mar 19 15:37 a.out
klutt@desktop:/tmp$ clang f.c -O3 -O0; ls -l a.out
-rwxr-xr-x 1 klutt klutt 16704 Mar 19 15:37 a.out
klutt@desktop:/tmp$ clang f.c -O0 -O3; ls -l a.out
-rwxr-xr-x 1 klutt klutt 16752 Mar 19 15:37 a.out
```

Comment: thanks for the quick test. Binary size clearly supports your/our assumption.